# jCrop while uploading image?

Tags: jquery, jcrop

How can edit this fiddle so what user can upload image and then he can resize it and get preview?

I have this fiddle :

https://jsfiddle.net/dekkard/trbqhb55/

Right now its working when image is already uploaded. Any suggestion?
Problem is here in true size where i need to get natural width and naturalHeight but image is not uploaded yet.

```
 $.Jcrop('#imgcrop',{
      trueSize: [$('#imgcrop')[0].naturalWidth,$('#imgcrop')[0].naturalHeight],
      onSelect: getcroparea,
      onChange: updatePreview,
      aspectRatio: 1,
      setSelect: [80, 45, 100, 100]
    });
```